# telegram bot api php вытаскивание данных из json

Tags: php, json, telegram-bot

сделал бот в телеграме хочу с помощью php поймать информацию с json

вот мой код

```
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $TOKEN . '/getUpdates';
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
file_put_contents('file.txt', print_r($response, 1)."\n");

print_r($name=$response['message']['text']);
print_r($response);
```

хочу получить информацию с ['message']['text'] но пишет "Undefined index: message " как мне быть подскажите пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разложил бы ты этот json на элементы построчно, для понимания структуры, ато так в глазах рябит. Например, я вижу несколько сообщений и в итоге должно быть, например, `$response[0]['message']['text']`

Comment: @DrMcSheen, сделал как ты написал но все равно ошибка есть (Undefined offset: 0)

Comment: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($response);` приложите вывод текстом а не картинкой

Comment: @ArchDemon, спасибо за <pre> так понято стало json но как мне вытащить сам тест?

Comment: $response['result'][0]['message']['text']